# Pack expansion in variadic templates when ellipsis are on innermost element of a pattern

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, variadic-templates

I saw this example on [cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/parameter_pack). I am not clear on the pack expansion of the function arguments.

> **Function parameter list**
>
> In a function parameter list, if an ellipsis appears in a parameter
>   declaration (whether it names a function parameter pack (as in, Args
>   ... args) or not) the parameter declaration is the pattern:
>
> ```
> template<typename ...Ts> void f(Ts...) {}
> f('a', 1);  // Ts... expands to void f(char, int)
> f(0.1);     // Ts... expands to void f(double)
>
> template<typename ...Ts, int... N> void g(Ts (&...)[N]) {}
> int n[1];
> g<const char, int>("a", n); // Ts (&...)[N] expands to const char (&)[2], int(&)[1]
> ```
>
> Note: in this pattern, the ellipsis is the innermost element, not the
>   last element as in all other pack expansions.

Comment: This line doesn't compile (nor does it make much sense). Must be a typo. Where did you get it from?

Comment: I edited the link where the code sample is from. It's under `Function parameter list`, and the example given is `template<typename ...Ts, int... N> void g(Ts (&...)[N]) {}`. Sorry, it compiles but it gives a warning instead. @Igor You must have your compiler settings to error on warnings.

Comment: Still [does not compile](http://ideone.com/l8DjF8) for me.

Comment: Blame C's declarator syntax. `Alias<T[N]>&...` with `template<class T> using Alias = T;`.

Comment: @Igor Whoops, I was using clang and not gcc.

Comment: @Xeo no! blame bad teachers that don't teach how to do this thing... man I'm tired of talking how to read C and C++ declarations..... it's just like a *expression* people! read it that way please... 
stackoverflow.com/a/21299100 
stackoverflow.com/a/13076065

Comment: @Igor Try replacing it with `template<typename ...Ts, int... N> void g (Ts (&...x) [N]) `. I don't know if that changes the meaning, though.

Comment: @pepper_chico: Except that system is terrible and produces unreadable declarations.

Comment: @DeadMG I think that's opinion, you see that, I don't, but in any case, our opnions don't matter, we can only accept and learn it the way it is.

Comment: @pepper_chico: Or we could use type traits and metaprogramming to express them much more clearly.

Comment: I withdraw my proposed fix in comments, here with clang 3.5 the thing just compiles with a warning about naming the parenthesized pack...

Answer (score 8):

This [works](http://ideone.com/LsNHai):

```
template<typename ...Ts, int... N> void g(Ts (&...array)[N]) {}
int n[1];
g<const char, int>("a", n); // Ts (&...)[N] expands to const char (&)[2], int(&)[1]
```

but apparently many compilers have a problem if you skip the name `array`.  I don't know if this is a quirk of the compilers or of the standard (both are reasonable: this is a serious bit of corner-case syntax).

As noted by @Xeo, a less obtuse way to deal with the declaration syntax of C is to cheat our way around the issue:

```
template<typename T> using Type = T;
template<typename... Ts, int... N> void g( Type<Ts[N]>&... ) {}
```

is easier to parse and removes the need for (at least some) compilers to have a variable name.

Comment: There has been a related defect [CWG 1234](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/cwg_defects.html#1234); I think the grammar doesn't allow it: the `...` in the *declarator-id* requires an *id-expression*, and the `...` in the *noptr-abstract-pack-declarator* cannot be inside parentheses, as far as I can see. I.e. there's a counterpart missing to the *noptr-abstract-declarator* : `(` *ptr-abstract-declarator* `)`

Comment: @dyp Yes, it seems like it compiles differently if you don't add a name.

Comment: @dyp "voted into WP" in 2011.. so is it legal C++1y?

Comment: @Cubbi FDIS status means ["A DR issue not resolved in the FCD but included in the Final Draft International Standard advanced for balloting at the March, 2011 WG21 meeting."](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/cwg_active.html) (FDC = Final Committee Draft) So AFAIK *that* defect is resolved in the C++11 Standard. However, I mentioned it only as a *related* defect. It's not the same issue, as far as I can tell.

Comment: @dyp I get it now, thank you. Switched my example to using a name. (btw, clang describes this quite well "warning: ISO C++11 requires a parenthesized pack declaration to have a name")

Comment: @dyp Turns out there is a defect exactly about this issue: [CWG  #1488](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_active.html#1488)

Comment: @Cubbi Wow thanks! Good to know I didn't mess up in the analysis of the declaration syntax ;)